# ffmpeg: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ruby, bash, ffmpeg

I have a situation where `ffmpeg` is throwing an error:

```
Invalid data found when processing input
```

I've reviewed other answers here, but my situation is different.  I generate in `Ruby`, a text file with a list of input files I want to concatenate together into one large video.

I generate in `Ruby`, the command meant for `bash`, which is also output for me to manually copy:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i /Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/randoms.txt /Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/final.mp4
```

Throws an error:

```
/Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/randoms.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Here is that file:

```
file '/Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/0CEDC3CA-4571-4271-9938-A161EC2A887B.mov'
file '/Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/0D25D907-D053-443B-AFC6-9F12B1711BBF.mov'
file '/Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/6A272808-7706-435D-801E-ACE6B42EC749.mov'
file '/Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/6E9BA2F1-C5E7-4C1C-B290-D116105732FA.mov'
file '/Volumes/Dragon2/Yums/0A41C7B7-74CE-484E-B029-3AE57B8BB4EA.mov'
```

When `bash` runs it, it complains about the input file **randoms.txt** having invalid data.  When I copy and paste the very same command in `bash`, it works fine.  I'm stumped as to how the two are different and why `ffmpeg` is not happy when initiated in the `shell`.

How can I get this to work?  What am I missing?  Cheers

EDIT: Original `ruby` code:

```
`clear`
require 'pathname'
require 'pp'

s = '/Volumes/Dragon2/Yums'
files = []

Dir.foreach(s) do |path|
  files << "#{ s }/#{ path }"  
end

result = files.sample(files.size)           # randomizer

f = File.open("#{ s }/randoms.txt", 'w+')
result.each_with_index do |item, i|
  pp "#{ i }: #{ item }" if item.include?('mov')
  f << "file '#{ item }'\n" if item.include?('mov')
end

`echo `

File.delete("#{ s }/final.mp4") if File.exists?("#{ s }/final.mp4")
s = "ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i #{ s }/randoms.txt #{ s }/final.mp4"
puts s

sleep 3
`#{ s }`
```

I have also tried `system s` as well with the same error.  The syntax is generated fine, output fine, operates fine manually.

Comment: It's not clear here how Ruby factors in. Are you running that from Ruby? If so, where's the Ruby code?

Comment: I don't see how `ruby` is the culprit as it's a system call from `ruby`, but I will edit the post.

Comment: If it's not a factor, then safer to just remove the tag. Remember that filenames can have spaces in them, so from Ruby you *must* call [`shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/String.html#method-i-shellescape) when introducing those sorts of arguments. It's probably safer to launch using [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) than the really weak backticks method. This way you can specify arguments specifically instead of leaving it up to the shell to parse them.

Comment: OK, implemented `Shellwords.escape(item)` for the addition, but the sample files don't have spaces.  I still get the same error.

Comment: @tadman Also used `open3` with the same error.  `stderr` is the same reported error.

Comment: The good news about `open3` is it gives you more control over the process, you can see what it's doing before it's done, which is useful if you want to report status. If you have bad input data, though, no amount of Ruby can help you. Check that your files are valid.

Comment: @tadman Yes, like I said it works just fine manually.  The very same syntax generated in the `ruby` script itself.  And the source files are valid as well.  That's why it's so confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I needed `f.close` to write the file so `ffmpeg` could read from it.  But the `shellwords` was also key.  Thank you .